# std::thread::join not returning

Tags: c++, multithreading, std

I am attempting to multithread my program and am trying to use a separate thread to run a specific function. However, whenever I call the join() function on said thread, it never returns, and the program will stop responding. I am checking that the thread is joinable before so.

Here is what I have:

```
static std::thread receiveThread = std::thread(&Server::receiveData, this);
if (receiveThread.joinable())
    {
        receiveThread.join();
        receiveThread = std::thread(&Server::receiveData, this);
    }
```

Comment: If `join()` never returns it means that the execution thread is still running. `joinable` does not mean that you can call `join()` and it will return immediately. It means that it is valid to call the given `std::thread`'s `join()` function, and it will return whenever its execution thread finishes, if it's still running, or returns immediately.

Comment: `join` waits until the thread finished execution. Apparently your thread still waits for something.

Comment: Check if `Server::receiveData` function ever returns. Only then would `receiveThread` exit and only then would calling `join()` on it return.

Comment: Note that calling `joinable()` does not tell you that `join()` will return immediately. It's for something completely different; it tells you whether the `std::thread` object manages a thread of execution that can be joined. A default-constructed thread is not joinable, and a thread that has been detached is not joinable. In your code example, `joinable()` will return `true`.

Comment: For performance reasons, consider using thread pools

Answer (score 1):

`std::thread::join` returns only after the thread (that is owned by the thread wrapper) returns. If the thread in question never returns, then the call to `std::thread::join` never returns either.

Comment: OKay thanks. How to then write a function that can be used to terminate the thread when we know that the join is not going to return?